# Combine collection and relation Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to integrate the relation columns into the parent collection?

```
$r = User::with('contactDetails')->get();
```

Then be able to do merge them into a single object without having to do `$r->user[0]->contactDetails->phonenumber` but instead just `$r->user[0]->phonenumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-transform) to iterate the collection and map on the existing object. It will be something like this;

```
User::with('contactDetails')
    ->get()
    ->transform(function (User $user) {
        $user->phonenumber = $user->contactDetails->phonenumber;
            
        return $user;
    });
```

Another and more performant way could be using `join` since it is 1-to-1 relationship. Then you may put `phonenumber` into your select statement.